# Java class object in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am working on a database, which requires user to register and login. When the use registers, the data gets stored into a room database.
For the registration purpose, Kotlin code is used. But I want to use a Object of java class inside that Kotlin code.

Therefore, my query is it possible to initialise an object of Java class inside a Kotlin code?

For example:
**user.java**

```
package ...

public class User {
    /*   The credentials of a user. */
    String userName, password, bID;
    /* Last message */
    String lastMessage;

    public User(String userName, String password, String bID, String lastMessage) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
        this.bID = bID;
        this.lastMessage = lastMessage;
    }
    ....
}
```

**register.kt:**

```
package ...

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_register.*

class RegisterActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register)

//        handler= DatabaseHelper(this)
            val handler= DatabaseHelper(this)


        User user = new user();
        btnLogRegister.setOnClickListener {
            onBackPressed()
        }
        reg_button.setOnClickListener{
            handler.insertUserData(reg_bluetooth_name.text.toString(),reg_username.text.toString(),reg_password.text.toString())
                Toast.makeText(this,"Values Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

        }
    }


}
```

I want to insert the java class object inside the **register** .kt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
User user = new User( ) 
//to this line
val user = User ( )
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use data class in kotlin like below

```
data class User (
  val userName : String = "",
  val password : String = "",
  val bID : String = "",
  val lastMessage : String = ""
)
```

How to use it

```
reg_button.setOnClickListener{
            handler.insertUserData(User(reg_bluetooth_name.text.toString(),reg_username.text.toString(),reg_password.text.toString()))
                Toast.makeText(this,"Values Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For kotlin, use data class, and to enjoy more features of kotlin like checking for nullability make you class like this,

```
data class User (var userName : String?,var password : String?,var bID : String?,var lastMessage : String?
)
```

Using var enable use to get both setters and getters whereas val will only give you getters. Note that the

```
`User (var userName : String?,var password : String?,var bID : String?,var lastMessage : String?)`
```

is the primary constructor and you can create more.

And in you activity you can force unwrap the values as shown in the code or use default values.

```
reg_button.setOnClickListener{
            handler.insertUserData(reg_bluetooth_name.text.toString()!,reg_username.text.toString()!,reg_password.text.toString()!)
                Toast.makeText(this,"Values Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

        }
```